# Why jQuery click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to expand the grid view by clicking  pus image on the gridview. But my below code is not working. How can i do this? 
Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
});
$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
});
```

Comment: I recommend using classes, ids and checking jQuery version - if you have 3 `.live` won't work - use `.on('click',`

Comment: live is deprecated. use .on instead

Comment: I have the version 3 . I used .on . But it's not working.

Comment: Change `$("[src*=plus]").live("click", ..` to `$(document).on('click', '[src*=plus]', ..`

Comment: @Al-AminSuzan then use `.on` try using `console.log('hello')` inside the function and check output in developer tools to see if it comes through

Comment: Show us your markup. Does your element really has `plus` in the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following script.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","[src*=plus]",function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });

    $(document).on("click","[src*=minus]",function(){
       $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using The Script

> $("[src*=plus]").on("click",
>   function () {
>       $(this).closest("tr").after("" + 
>       $(this).next().html() + "")
>       $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png"); }); $("[src*=minus]").on("click", function () {
>       $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
>       $(this).closest("tr").next().remove(); });

Have a look on the below URL to have a complete details of using .click method
https://api.jquery.com/click/